# Exporting Oracle table with multiple geometry columns to gpkg by using ogr2ogr

Tags: ogr, ogr2ogr, oracle-spatial, geopackage

I am using ogr2ogr to export a table in Oracle to GPKG. The table in Oracle has two columns (GEOMETRY_2, GEOMETRY_20) with geometry info.

[image]

I am using the following ogr2ogr command to export the table into GPKG.

```
ogr2ogr -progress -f "GPKG" C:\Users\test\test.gpkg  OCI:{username}/{password}@{db_alias}:{table_name -sql "select * from TableName@XXX" -append -nln "TableName" -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geometry -a_srs EPSG:31287
```

The command creates the GPKG as in the image. What I do not understand, which geometry columns (GEOMETRY_2, GEOMETRY_20) ogr2ogr uses to create the GEOMETRY column in GPKG. If it uses GEOMETRY_2, is there any way still have GEOMETRY_20  in the GPKG?

[image]

Comment: What's the difference between the two geometry columns?

Comment: The same object is generalized with two different tolerances and the columns are representing.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with this situation. But it's an intersting one. What happens if you load the gpkg in a GIS? Does it display the data?

Comment: Yes, I can open the gpkg in QGIS. As far as I see, if I do not specify the geometry column name, it peaks GEOMETRY_2 and I can see the objects in QGIS. But if I run this command `-sql "select ID, GEOMETRY_20 as GEOMETRY from tablename` , I do get the geometry from GEOMETRY_20  and again it is displayed in QGIS

Comment: Does that not answer your own question than? Or am I missing something?

Comment: It does not as I want to keep both GEOMETRY_20 and GEOMETRY_2 in gpkg. And I was interested in to know how ogr2ogr selects/ decides to the geometry column out of two if it is not explicitly define

Comment: Right, well both columns are kept in the gpkg. QGIS will draw the geometry based on the first geometry column unless specified otherwise like in your SQL command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation about how the support for multiple geometry fields is implemented in GDAL is in https://gdal.org/development/rfc/rfc41_multiple_geometry_fields.html. It does not say clearly which geometry is the default geometry but I suppose that it is the first one that GDAL finds. Better not to trust on the defaults but select the geometry explicitly with SQL just like you have already done.

When it comes to GeoPackage, you are out of luck because the GeoPackage standard allows only one geometry field. Excerpt from the standard:

> Requirement 30
>
> A feature table SHALL have only one geometry column. Feature data
> models [B23] from non-GeoPackage implementations that have multiple
> geometry columns per feature table MAY be transformed into GeoPackage
> implementations with a separate feature table for each geometry type
> whose rows have matching integer primary key values that allow them to
> be joined in a view with the same column definitions as the
> non-GeoPackage feature     data model with multiple geometry columns.

You must select some other format or model your data in a different way. SpatiaLite does support multiple geometry columns and is otherwise rather close to GeoPackage.